# WorkAround Jquery Datatable in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

I created a sidebar menu in which it calls its page via target. No problem with that. I tried adding datatable and it works fine but when I switched between menu datatable will not work anymore.

Here's my code

In `app.blade.php`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/menu.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="public/adminlte/dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
<script src="public/adminlte/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="public/adminlte/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

And my blade is this ( I did not include the HTML since it's very long but I'm calling a script inside the blade)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
function loadService(){
    
    $('#tblService').DataTable();
}

loadService();
```

I'm not sure if I'm making some sort of mistake here but please advise.

Here's the video of what I meant on the error

https://www.loom.com/share/a533c6a34a9c43a194f6d301e109695b

Answer (score 0):

try to store your DataTable instance into variable to avoid creating of datatable few times:

```js
let dataTableInstance = null;

function loadService() {
  if (!dataTableInstance )
    dataTableInstance = $('#tblService').DataTable();
  }
}
```